# Can't convert Realm list from List<SpecificObject> to List<Object>

Tags: swift, realm

I'm working on a library for Realm synchronization using CloudKit (https://github.com/caiyue1993/IceCream).

What I'm trying to do is to access a realm object property that is a `List<SpecificObject>` via `parentObject["propertyName"]`.

Since I can't directly reference the `SpecificObject` type, so I'm trying to cast this to `List<Object>` like this:

`parentObject["propertyName"] as? List<Object>`

but this produces `nil`.

Same result for casting to `AnyRealmCollection<Object>`.

It successfully casts to `ListBase`, which is a superclass of `List<T>`, but this is useless.

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong, or should I submit this as an issue to the RealmCocoa repo?

Comment: Are you trying to select the value from the database and need to be a array of the object ?

Comment: Why can't you directly access SpecificObject? You know the object and it's in a list.

Comment: I can’t use a SpecificObject since the library I’m woking on should support any object that conforms to my protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Since generic types in Swift are invariant, `List<Object>` and `List<ObjectSubclass>` are two completely unrelated types. Hence the failing cast in your code.

Without knowing the exact type that's being stored in the `List`, it's impossible to transform a `List<ObjectSubclass>` to a `List<Object>` type due to them being invariant.

Comment: That would not be possible, the `parentObject["propertyName"]` has the type `Any`

Comment: @AndriiLiakh in your question you state that you have a collection of type `List<ObjectSubclass>`, so which is it? `Any` is not a concrete type, so what is the actual type of `parentObject["propertyName"]`? Or rather, how do you get that property?

Comment: `parentObject["propertyName"]` behaves like accessing `[String: Any]` here, so even though my collection has the type `List<ObjectSubclass>`, it still has to be cast to it.

Comment: I have the type stored in a variable like this: `let type = getClassFromString(className)`, but it seems that it's not possible to do `List<type>` either.

Comment: @AndriiLiakh if `parentObject` is of type `[String:Any]`, why don't you simply cast it to `List<ObjectSubclass>` first, before iterating through it?

Comment: Because the code is unaware of the exact `Object` subclass that's going to be present here.

Comment: @AndriiLiakh well in that case what you are asking for is not possible due to the invariance of generic types